# Using Apache 2.0 libraries to test GPL 2 library

Tags: apache-2.0, gpl-2

I'm making a library which is a derivative work of openjdk that's released under GPL 2.0 with Classpath Exception, so my library is obviously GPL 2.0+CE too. I'd like to write tests for my library using testng and wiremock which are licensed under Apache 2.0, thus incompatible with GPL 2.0. As far as know, I'm not allowed to use those libraries in GPL 2.0 code, but do my tests need to be GPL? Can I release main library under GPL 2.0 and tests under i.e. MIT? And here is one interesting bit, openjdk has links to Apache 2.0 libraries in their GPL 2.0 code. Does it mean they themselves breached GPL license?

Comment: "openjdk has links to Apache 2.0 libraries in their GPL 2.0 code."  - But OpenJDK is not under the vanilla GPL 2 license -- as you have noted -- it is GPL2 with a linking (classpath) exception. The purpose of the linking (classpath) exception is to allow linking with other software, as you have described, without requiring that the other software also be GPL2 as well.

Comment: "I'm making a library which is a derivative work of openjdk ... so my library is *obviously* GPL 2.0+CE too." -- The 'obviously' part may not be so obvious. If you read the exception carefully on: https://openjdk.org/legal/gplv2+ce.html, they say clearly that you may "delete this exception statement from your version" if you wish. So for your derived library, it's up to you.

Comment: Isn't classpath exception working the other way round? I thought CE means "if you link to our GPL+CE library, then you are not obliged to release your software under GPL". But GPL code with CE or not is still not allowed to link to incompatible libraries.

Comment: Someone with more knowledge and experience with this license really out to provide an official answer for this, but my understanding is that the classpath exception (CE) was specifically added to make it possible to link with (binary) Apache 2.0 code. The exception as stated allows linking with any "independent module". In theory that other independent module could be of any license other than vanilla GPL2, since the license compatibility problem appears to have been caused by GPL2 itself.